# Windows form from Powershell encoding

Tags: powershell, windows-forms-designer

please help me. 
I have a problem when I'm trying to print text in different language on Windows form from Power shell. Here is my part of code:

```
"[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
Dear user...
Уважаемый пользователь...)"
```

But on the form I've got some nonsense symbols for second sentence. English language works fine, but Russian won't. What should I do?
Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the script with Unicode or UTF-8 encoding. In Notepad click *File → Save As...*  and select the encoding from the dropdown list at the bottom o f the dialog.

Also, the double quotes need to be *inside* the parentheses:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Dear user...
Уважаемый пользователь...")
```